# dynamically change on-tap attribute

Tags: javascript, polymer

what i am trying to do is change the function that on-tap calls based on spa route. here is what i have tried (working inside a custom element)

```
this.$.menuButton.attr['on-tap'] = "{{newFunction}}";
```

also

```
this.$.menuButton.on-tap = "{{newFunction}}";
```

as well as many other attempts none have worked. how do i change the value on a attribute that contains a - in the name? if this isn't doable what would be the recommended method for changing the on-tap function dynamically?

Comment: Using dot notation, you cannot have a hyphen, so you must retain bracket notation here. I don't know polymer, but can't you just assign the event a function reference?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `ontap`? `onXXX` attributes don't usually have any punctuation.

Comment: yes i am sure the attribute is on-tap (it's a polymer thing).  i guess i could create a new function that fires a event and listen to that event and change what the function does there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the on-* declarative event mapping, you should be using event listeners.

```
this.addEventListener('tap', this.myFunction);
this.addEventListener('tap', this.newFunction);
```

It's basically the same thing. If you need `(event, detail, sender)` arguments, though, you have to pass them yourself.

[API Reference](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping)

Comment: this was a approach i was planing on using and i may come back to it. i am going to give the declarative route a shot first. thank you for you answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd definitely go with whatever Eric Bidelman says. Celebrities, jeez... :)

Comment: after attempting the declarative method i have decided to go with this eventListener method. mainly because i am already using similar eventListeners to change another link in my app. (this change being in a custom element through me for a loop) so i will have my on-tap fire a event i can listen for in my main.js then change the function called based on the app route. this way i can avoid needing a sender to change the handler. i wanted to use the other method to keep as much as i can included in the custom element. but lack on patience wins out again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go the declarative route, you can still use `on-*` handlers and data-binding to flip the handler:

```
<p on-tap="{{handler}}">Tap me to see what handler is set.</p>
<button on-click="{{setHandler}}" data-handler="oneHandler">Set Handler 1</button>

ready: function() {
  this.setHandler();
},
setHandler: function(e, detail, sender) {
  this.handler = !sender ? this.defaultHandler :  
                           this[sender.dataset.handler];
},
defaultHandler: function() {
  alert('default handler');
},
oneHandler: function() {
   alert('one handler');
}
```

http://jsbin.com/forame/1/edit